# Omit a column when running `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold`

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a situation where a multitude of very similar but not identical legacy databases is being reverse engineered into a C# model using `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold`.  Due to the variety of the databases there is no single definitive source.  The closest one have a column in a couple of tables that should not be in the C# model.

I had a look at https://github.com/dotnet/efcore but could not immediately see options or paths in the code allowing this finegrainedness.

Is there a way to add metadata to the database to skip columns is skipped?

Comment: I only know of filtering the tables; it doesn't mean it's not possible but there are limitations to reverse engineering with the cli. If it's just a single column in a couple tables, couldn't you just omit it manually after the entity classes are generated?

Comment: EF Core Power Tools can do that for you

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do this as there is no option for that in scaffolding options
Take a look at [DatabaseModelFactoryOptions.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/8144d50ec0d15b87c35a9a3a425b1faadafb87f1/src/EFCore.Relational/Scaffolding/DatabaseModelFactoryOptions.cs) and [EntityFrameworkCore.psm1](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/8144d50ec0d15b87c35a9a3a425b1faadafb87f1/src/EFCore.Tools/tools/EntityFrameworkCore.psm1) for more info

Comment: it might be doable by adding metadata to the database?